# Dart naming convention

Tags: dart

Why in dart we have `String` not `string`

Other types are in lower case

- `int` not `Int`
- `double` not `Double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the naming was to make Dart more familiar to people coming from Java (or C#, but mostly Java).
That's why `int`, `double`, `bool` and `void` are lower-case and `String` is capitalized, because that's what they were in Java (although `boolean` was considered too damn long).
The `num` type got looped in too, because it's so closely tied to `int` and `double`, and `dynamic` was lower case to mark it as a *special* type, like `void`.
(Special types added later, like `FutureOr` or `Never`, were not made lower case because that increased the risk of conflicting with existing variable names, something the original language didn't have to worry about.)

Dart does not have primitive types like, say, Java. All Dart values are objects, and you can call methods on them.

Answer (score -1):

Primitive types are starting with lower case (int, double, char ...). String is not a primitive type its an object therefore it doesn't start with lower case

Comment: Do you know why string is not primitive? is there any primitive definition in dart ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp you can read that (don't mind that its bases on java)
But in most simple terms String is and array of chars. Modern languages such as dart alocate memory for the String content "behind the scenes", you don't need to do it manualy. For example in C if u want a dynamically allocated string (https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings take a look here).
But most important thing in not primitive type is that you can call methods on it.

Comment: Dart does not have primitive types like Java, so the linked article does not apply to Dart. All Dart values are objects, and you can call methods on `int` instances.

Comment: I've just checked that Irn is right. Oh man I wouldn't know this for my entire life if not this question